# How to classify a group of events as a whole using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I want to automate a daily task where I check a list of application errors of the last 24 hours.

- Every error can belong to one of six different pools
- Every erro has a timestamp
- I don't know in advance how many errors I'll have in each pool

I have to CLASSIFY the status of each pool as GREEN, YELLOW or RED using a rule like this:

- If the are no error at all on one pool -> GREEN
- If there are errors in the pool but a specific error is not persisting for more than 4 hours consecutively -> YELLOW
- If there are errors in the pool and a specific error is persisting for more than 4 hours consecutively -> RED

The problem is easily solvable using conventional programming or a fuzzy approach but I want to know how to solve it (if possible) using Machine Learning approach.

In classification tecniques I've seen so far there is a TRAINING SET composed by TRAINING EXAMPLES that possesses certain FEATURES.

A classifier is trained against this training set, is furter validated against a TEST SET and the resulting MODEL is used to classify new instances.

So the classification is "for a new single instance" and not "of the whole set".

If I use, say, an ANN I'll have a node for each feature every sample has and

- I train the ANN through all training samples
- I test against the test set
- I'll feed the resulting model with new cases to be classified (one at a time, individually).

The task I need to automate is different:
For each pool (I'll use the same logic for everyone separately) I have to classyfy it (as a whole, not a new single event/error) as GREEN, YELLOW or RED based on a variable number of events/errors temporally separated.

My question is: It's a problem I can solve using ML approach? If yes How I've to approch the problem (I need just some hint, not a complete solution).

Comment: Look into random forests in classification mode.  Your question is too broad for an answer here.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, but if you mean to pre-elaborate data to extract information such as how many error I have in the pool and if some error persisted for more than 4 hours and then use a decision tree to do the classification, this is not the way I want (too trivial, no need for a decision tree when I can use a pair of if statement).
What I'm looking for is a way to arrange and feed the data (pretty much as they are) to a model and obtain a "group labeling" of the entire pool (not of every single event/error).  
It's quite like a state machine and maybe it's not a solvable problem with ML

Comment: I don't think you grasp how machine learning works.  You build a model using your data or a subset of your data, and then you can predict outputs using that model.

Comment: @Tim, all classification algos I've seen so far are used to classify new given input example. Here I have multiple example and I have to label/classify all as a group. What I'm asking is if this kind of problem is solvable using ML and how to arrange data to do it.

Comment: Ah...so you are saying you want to form groups without even knowing what the groups are?  Then what you are looking for is _unsupervised_ machine learning.  One example of this is a clustering analysis.

Comment: No @Tim, as far as I've learned both unsupervised clustering and supervised classification are used to label new instances (put them in a group). In my example an instance is an error/event but I don't want to label a new event/error but to attach a label at a whole group of events/errors (a pool). This is what I'm not able to figure out how to do and if it's doable and how with ML.

Comment: You should update your question with actual data.  It isn't clear to me what the problem is.  How do you assign a color to each error?

Comment: If you read carefully my problem is exactely that I don't want to classify every error but a GROUP of error. the label is green if there are no errors (the group/pool is empty), the label is yellow if there are errors but a single type of error is not repeated for more than 4 hours, red if some error type is repeated for more than 4 hours. Errors are retries and generally happens every 5 mins if persists and are not resolved

Comment: Sorry if I was not enough clear..

Comment: After reading again in this new light, your problem might not need machine learning.  The pool color can be computed on the fly using your rules.  I think in general you will have to check every log message because you won't know the color for certain.